# nodemon ignore directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

In a Universal Javascript app, I would like nodemon to ignore client directory changes.

I have tried the following:

```
"devStart": "nodemon server/server.js --ignore 'client/*' --exec babel-node",
"devStart": "nodemon server/server.js --ignore 'client/' --exec babel-node",
"devStart": "nodemon server/server.js --ignore client/ --exec babel-node",
"devStart": "nodemon --ignore 'client/*' server/server.js --exec babel-node",
"devStart": "nodemon --ignore 'client/' server/server.js --exec babel-node",
"devStart": "nodemon --ignore client/ server/server.js --exec babel-node",
```

None of these work.

File structure:

```
+-server
+-client
+-package.json <------- where nodemon script is
```

However this is not working. Pretty sure it is a pattern issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest store your nodemon configurations in `nodemon.json` file. would make it cleaner.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Thanks for the tip. Any tips for the actual question?

Comment: pretty sure its just the path to client thats off - should be `./client/*`, or `client/*`

Comment: can you try without the `'` marks around and also use `.` instead of `..`: `'./client/*'` and also without `*`?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ edited `package.json` is actually in the same directory as `server` and `client`

Comment: just to be clear, you are running it through `npm run devStart`, right? does it work if you write the exact same thing directly in command line?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ yes sir I am

Comment: The command `nodemon server/server.js --ignore client/ --exec babel-node` should work. I just tested it out. Make sure that you're ending `nodemon` after saving your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You need to replace `..` with `.`, or just reference `client/` directly, also you will need to remove the asterisk:

```
"devStart": "nodemon --ignore ./client/ --exec babel-node src/server.js"
```

Or

```
"devStart": "nodemon --ignore client/ --exec babel-node src/server.js"
```

According to nodemon docs this is how to ignore a directory via command line:

```
nodemon --ignore lib/ --ignore tests/
```

Also note that nodemon will only restart the node process, if you change the npm script you will need to kill the process and re-run `npm run devStart`

Comment: Edited my `package.json` is actually in the same directory as `client` and `src`

Comment: have updated the answer to remove the asterisk - nodemon docs say to follow this pattern: `nodemon --ignore lib/ --ignore tests/`

Comment: I tried that also. Could it be the order of things? Should the directory nodemon is expected to run come after the ignore?

Comment: Ok got it. I was expecting the server reload to actually reload the devStart script. Turns out I had to kill the process and run `npm run devStart` again. If you can update your answer to reflect this I will accept it. @hackerrdave

Comment: "you will need to remove the asterisk" worked for me! Thank you.

Comment: I had to remove the quotes around `client/`

Comment: REMOVE THE QUOTES works for me: `nodemon --ignore client src/server.js`

Answer (score 58):

In the very likely circumstance that you're using `nodemon` in a configuration file, you can create a separate configuration entry for those files to be ignored. Bonus, a cleaner looking `nodemon` call, especially if files to ignore grows large.

For example, this `package.json` instructs `nodemon` to ignore directory `test`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
      "ignore": ["test/*"]
  }
}
```

Find the complete instructions for nodemon configuration file settings [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).

As in the other answer, be sure to restart `nodemon` for the configuration changes to take effect.

Answer (score 7):

Create `nodemon.json` in your project root that looks something like this:

```
{
  "ignore": ["db.json"]
}
```

This is an alternative to using package.json as seen in Andrew Philips answer

See [docs](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files)

Answer (score 4):

just so you all know, i was using this pattern to exclude directories :

`node_modules/**`

but it led to using a LOT of watchers: nearly 500000 on one of my projects
and now i use

`node_modules/`

which uses only 134 watchers.

**Always monitor your work**

Comment: Any guidance on how you monitor these watchers?

Comment: For those who stumble across this, you can add `"verbose": true,` to your `nodemon.json` file and it'll show you the count of files being watched.

Comment: @dKen i used this to count inotify handles : https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use something like this to run nodemon only in a specific folder. This way you don't have to add multiple `--ignore` parameters.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "devStart": "cd ./server/ && nodemon ./server.js"
  }
}
```