# Nodemon: is it possible to restart the Node js server on chages ONLY in backend files and NOT in static frontend files?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Recently, I've started using Nodemon to auto-refresh my Node js server on changes in files (it's soooo convenient: previously, I used to stop it manually with sigint and restart the project in the command line again). What I did is installed Nodemon on my PC globally (*npm install nodemon -g*), and now I start my project with the command *nodemon app.js* (instead of usual *node app.js*), and everything seems to be great ... except for one thing that pretty annoys me: the server keeps restarting also on changes in my frontend files which are made static in Express by the command *app.use(express.static('frontend'))* – which is purposeless, because I don't need to restart the Node js server to apply changes in such files (simply to reload a page in a browser is enough). So, is there a way to "learn" nodemon to ignore static frontend files and not to restart the server on changes in them?

Comment: you can use `nodemon` with the `--ignore` flag passing the folder containing your static files. For instance `nodemon --ignore assets/*`

Comment: your question can be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120004/nodemon-exclusion-of-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved by installing nodemon locally + adding to package.json the following code (as offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55544467/14282340)):

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon app.js"
    },
    "nodemonConfig": {
         "ignore": [
             "frontend/*"
         ]
    }
```

Now, if I launch the project either with *nodemon app.js*, or with *npm start*, changes in all the files within the *frontend* folder are ignored.